# Time travel wars

Tags: technology, science-fiction, time-travel

I am wondering how futuristic wars would play out if time travel was an available technology, sort of like the Time War in *Doctor Who*. assuming a galactic war where both sides are fairly evenly matched and both have FTL travel. Time travel, however, is only available to the military forces of both sides.

Comment: What are the rules of time travel in your universe? Can you go back and time and change things? How are paradoxes resolved?

Answer (score 3):

There is a really long answer to this that involves a massive amount of space-time mechanics and cosmological theory, but ultimately I'll try to boil this down to the bare basics I can to explain what would happen based on current temporal theory.

First of all, we're assuming that time travel IS possible and that it can occur in both directions.

If we make those two assumptions, then there's three theories about the consequences of time travel that we have to consider;

1) Mutable Past - This theory says that if you go back in time and make a change to your past, then when you return the impacts of those changes have filtered through the timeline and you'd be the only person (on your return) to remember the alternate timeline. Ultimately, in this theory, time travel will eventually be impossible. Why? Because someone at some point will render a change in the time line that makes it impossible; they'll kill the grandparents of its inventor, accidentally create a world where energy generation is severely limited, etc. This is in part what Dr Who refers to when they mention time-locks et al. In a war, time travel would be used destructively and this is an extremely probable result.

2) Immutable Past - In this theory, time travel will always be possible if it's possible because whatever you've done in the past has already happened; in other words, there's no possible way to change the past, even if you go back there. Your visit is a part of history and the changes you make had always been made. In this world, time travel would be largely used for intelligence gathering and to 'ensure' that key events take place. This means that it would be used in a support role, not a combat role. These are your intelligence operatives.

3) 'Many-Worlds' theory - in this theory you can change the past but every time you do, you spin off another parallel 'dimension' (not the right term but the actual result would be understood as such), meaning that you'd soon find yourself spread over many parallel dimensions and the ultimate impact you'd have on your specific dimension would be zero. In essence, you wouldn't bother because all you'd be doing is creating another sand pit to play in.

Wars are not won with weapons and soldiers; we've known that since the days of Sun Tzu. They're won with supply lines, intelligence and superior strategy. The role of time travel in such an evenly matched war would be to provide new and superior intelligence to the side engaging in it, and support critical past actions that have to be supported. To do otherwise would be risking either massive paradoxes or abject failure if the past is remembered differently to the outcome you're trying to create, regardless of which theory above turns out to be true.

Comment: It is a shame that this was put on hold because it would lead to some wild conversations.  Immutable past for example can have a few loopholes which make it useful offensively, ...but that is a story for another question.

Comment: Very true. I understand why the question was put on hold but it would be a nice topic to explore more completely one day